# Easiest way to update dictionary values from a list?

Tags: python

Here is my original dictionary:

```
original_dict = {
    "Teachers": {
        "Maths": "Kiran",
        "Physics": "David",
        "Chemistry": "Ravi"
    }
}
```

I want to change the values of Maths, Physics and Chemistry from a list:

```
my_new_values_list = ["Alex", "Rahul", "Micheal"]
```

I want my dictionary to look like this after changing values of my dictionary from a list:

```
    {
    "Teachers": {
        "Maths": "Alex",
        "Physics": "Rahul",
        "Chemistry": "Micheal"
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me to automatically update dictionary values from a list in Python?

Comment: Please note this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; give a [mre] showing what you have tried and what the specific problem with it is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm really sorry. From next time I will definitely take care about it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
original_dict = {
    "Teachers": {
        "Maths": "Kiran",
        "Physics": "David",
        "Chemistry": "Ravi"
    }
}


my_new_values_list = ["Alex", "Rahul", "Micheal"]
original_dict['Teachers'] = dict(zip(original_dict['Teachers'].keys(), my_new_values_list))

print(original_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Teachers': {'Maths': 'Alex', 'Physics': 'Rahul', 'Chemistry': 'Micheal'}}
```